# Exclude all Files from Rewrite (NGINX to APACHE Migration)

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

My URL structure is like

```
http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?dir=dir1
```

To be able to access it from

```
http://www.example.com/folder/dir1
```

and at the same time redirect the 1st URL to 2nd one, my htaccess (in 'folder') is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dir=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/? index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The Redirect **and** Rewrite were working perfect until recently I switched from NGINX back to APACHE.
The trouble is that it is now also rewriting file extensions which I don't want!
How can I only apply it only to directories and exclude ALL files from it?

Comment: Remove `[solved]` from your title, post the solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted. That's how the site works: The first post contains the question, the later posts are the answers.

Comment: Done! I tried that yesterday but for some SO conditions, i wasn't able to answer my own question!

Comment: 48 hours after the creation of the answer, you can mark your answer as accepted, so that future readers can see that the posted answer *did* solve the problem. For more information on this, see this topic on meta: [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/169101?can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! :)

Actually had to add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

before the first rewrite!

So the htaccess looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^dir=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^(.+)/? index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```